# the usage of 'will be'

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

I saw this sentence in a supplementary book:

> "The food **will be** a couple of minutes"

I was wondering if I can use **will be** in other situations?

Like, when a landlord is trying to renovate a house and sell, they tell the buyer:

> "The house **will be** in 3 weeks"

Comment: Nope.  The first example is a special case, referring to when something will be delivered.  It's not idiomatic to use the wording in your second example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first is short for:

*’*the food will be {ready within}/{ready in} a couple of minutes. please have a seat'*

Applying the same notion to the second, it would read:

*'the house will be {ready within}/{ready in}in 3 weeks’*

The repetition of *within in*/*in in* makes it meaningless or at least very confusing.

The correct parallel version of the second is thus:

*'the house will be 3 weeks’* implying that *the house will be {ready in} 3 weeks

Comment: _the house will be 3 weeks_. Is this idiomatic?

Comment: I would suggest that it is short for _The food will be {arriving in} a couple of minutes._ Similarly a person who is on their way to join you, or is getting ready to go out with you, can say _I'll just be a couple of minutes_. You can't use it of a house being renovated without adding _ready, finished_ or similar.